# Need to understand some `ant fat/shaded` jar concepts

Tags: java, build, ant, fatjar

I'm trying to create a jar which will contain the other `runtime dependencies` jars.

I used following script

```
<jar destfile="MyApplication.jar">
  <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" /> 
  <!-- other options -->
  <manifest>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Main.MainClass" />
  </manifest>
</jar>
```

When I say other `runtime dependencies` jars, I was thinking those will be added as a full jar inside `MyApplication.jar`

Something like below.

`MyApplication.jar`

```
 --`lib/depedent1.jar`
 --`lib/depedent2.jar`
 -- my.class
 -- myAnother.class
```

But, what I found `MyApplication.jar` actually have all extracted content of `lib/depedent1.jar`/`lib/depedent2.jar`

I don't have any issue if the content is extracted but just curious that wouldn't it possible to create a jar with actually distinguished dependent jars inside?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Shaded/fat jar extract the content of dependencies inside it's parent jar

`MyApplication.jar`

```
-- com.lib1.corp.SomeClass.class
-- com.lib2.corp.AnotherClass.class
-- com.my.corp.myFirst.class
-- com.my.corp.myAnother.class
```